# How to get float working, inside a flex div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Just trying to float my divs to get them inline with each other. Since applying flex to the container div they prefer to act as block display. 
I'm sure it's something small I'm doing wrong.

```css
.box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 270px;
  position: block;
  min-height: 17em;
  max-width: 1600px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.lilbox {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px;
  padding 0px;
  max-width: 31.7%;
  max-height: 10%;
  float: left;
}
.lilbox img {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="second">
  <div class="lilbox">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    </br>
    <img src="Images/img.png" alt="img">
    <p>Blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="lilbox">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    </br>
    <p>Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="lilbox">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    </br>
    <p>Blah Blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `flex-direction: column`

Then play around with `align-items` and `justify-content` to align your content as you wish

```css
.box {
text-align: center;
padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px; 
margin: 0px 0px 0px 270px;
position: block;
min-height: 17em;
max-width: 1600px;
background-color: white;
display: flex;

}

.lilbox {
text-align: center;
display: inline;
margin: 5px;
padding 0px;
max-width: 31.7%;
max-height: 10%;
float: left;
}

.lilbox img{
max-width: 90%;
display: block;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="second">
    <div class="lilbox">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        </br><img src="Images/img.png" alt="img">
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lilbox">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        </br>
        <p>Blah Blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lilbox">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        </br>
        <p>Blah Blah</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Year and a half later - this was the answer I needed! Thanks!